# LNA operating in saturation

Tags: amplifier, rf, noise, saturation, low-noise-amplifier

What happens to an LNA noise figure when operated in saturation? I understand that there will be gain and linearity issues, but what about its noise figure? What is the mechanism which will lead to its deterioration?

Answer (score 0):

> *What happens to an LNA noise figure when operated in Saturation*

**Noise figure** is defined as the ratio of the input signal-to-noise ratio to the output signal-to-noise ratio so, if the output moves towards saturation then: -

- both signal and noise may reduce by the same amount or,
- the clipping/saturation may allow noise to remain more dominant whilst the signal reduces or,
- the noise may reduce more than the signal

In other words, it cannot be generally determined; you need to perform specific signal and circuit analysis to decide what might actually happen. May I suggest you use a simulator and try this out for yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a scenario where the noise figure would actually go down under this scenario?